# Preventing upgrading mysql on ubuntu when apt-get upgrade is run

Tags: apt, mysql

I want to make sure that `sudo apt-get upgrade` does not upgrade mysql 5.7.22 to the latest mysql GA 8.0.  Last time I ran this command mysql 5.7.20 was upgrading to mysql 5.7.22 automatically, which was ok but if it upgrades to mysql 8.x,  the production applications will stop working.

What command to execute to disable auto upgrade of mysql while keeping every other package on auto upgrade list.

Comment: I saw that before posting this question.  I guess I don't know how to make a list of all packages that involves in mysql setup.  I ran a list of installed packages and found many that includes the name "mysql" but I am not sure if there are packages (without the name mysql in them) that mysql depends on and if they get updated, mysql may not function.  It happens in Windows sometimes when you update an underlying library, the app depending on an older version stops.

Comment: You just have to put the mysql server package on hold. That should hold the dependencies as well

Comment: It would be considered very, very broken behavior if MySQL Server 5.7.x is automatically upgraded to 8.0 in an LTS distribution.  That's an entirely different version of the server.